# How can I change value of default([CustomStruct]) in C#?

Tags: c#

If I test following code:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int number;
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", default(MyStruct))
```

The result in console will be `[some namespace].MyStruct`

The question is how can I change the return of `default(MyStruct)` to something else?

Comment: What's your goal? Perhaps there's a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the behavior of the `default` keyword. It has predefined behavior for value, reference, and struct types.

> For structs, it will return each member of the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are value or reference types.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After further study, looks like I can override ToString method to change the result of print.
The default ToString implementation of value type is like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.GetType().ToString();
}
```

I can override it to print something else.